# indexing pyspark column based on intervals defined in other columns

Tags: indexing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe where I want to insert an ID column based on the column `pad_change`
My dataframe looks something like this:

```
|TOOL_ID|pad_change|DATE      |Pad_ID        |
+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
|59628  |1         |2021-05-22|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-23|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-23|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-24|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-25|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-26|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-27|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-27|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-28|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-05-29|null          |
|59628  |1         |2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-02|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-02|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-02|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-03|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|null          |
|59628  |1         |2021-06-05|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-06|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-07|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-08|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-08|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-09|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-09|null          |
|59628  |0         |2021-06-10|null          |
```

I would like the `Pad_ID` column to have the same value when `pad_change=1` until the next time it changes from 0 to 1.

Expected Output:

```
|TOOL_ID|pad_change|DATE      |Pad_ID        |
+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
|59628  |1         |2021-05-22|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-23|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-23|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-24|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-25|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-26|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-27|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-27|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-28|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |0         |2021-05-29|PAD_2021-05-22|
|59628  |1         |2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-03|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|59628  |1         |2021-06-05|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-06|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-07|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-08|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-08|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-09|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-09|PAD_2021-06-05|
|59628  |0         |2021-06-10|PAD_2021-06-05|
```

Is there a way to do this in Pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below solution creating 2 windows, one for creating a cumulative sum of pad_change for each group. Then you can use that helper column along with Tool_ID column for creating a new window with aggregation as `first`. Finally drop the helper column (`Win_`)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w = W.partitionBy("TOOL_ID").orderBy("DATE")\
                           .rangeBetween(W.unboundedPreceding,0)
w1 = W.partitionBy("TOOL_ID","Win_").orderBy("TOOL_ID")
out = (df.withColumn("Win_",F.sum("pad_change").over(w))
          .withColumn("Pad_ID",F.first("Pad_ID").over(w1)).drop("Win_"))
```

---

```
out.show(30)

+---+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
|   |TOOL_ID|pad_change|      DATE|        Pad_ID|
+---+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
|   |  59628|         1|2021-05-22|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-23|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-23|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-24|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-25|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-26|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-27|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-27|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-28|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-05-29|PAD_2021-05-22|
|   |  59628|         1|2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-02|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-03|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-04|PAD_2021-06-02|
|   |  59628|         1|2021-06-05|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-06|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-07|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-08|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-08|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-09|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-09|PAD_2021-06-05|
|   |  59628|         0|2021-06-10|PAD_2021-06-05|
+---+-------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: perfect!. Actually I have a TIME_SAMP column that I can use that is more granular than DATE. Let me try that